# multiplying huge numbers in JAVA

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, biginteger

I am trying to do this by add scanner to get user inputs, but I couldn't. You help me to improve this code by adding `Scanner` to get user input. I tried it but it get some error. I'm beginner to JAVA language.

```
import java.math.*;

public class BigIntegerMul {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    BigInteger int1 = new BigInteger("131224324234234234234313");
    BigInteger int2 = new BigInteger("13345663456346435648234313");
    BigInteger result = int1.multiply(int2);
    System.out.println(result);

}
}
```

Comment: `"i try it but it get some error."` -- we'll be much better able to help if you **show** us your attempt and your error message. `"You help me to improve this code by adding Scanner to get user input."` -- don't ask this please as you're asking others to do your work for you which is not ethical or right.

Answer (score 2):

To take `BigInteger` using `Scanner` you may use the following code snippet -

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BigIntegerMul {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    //BigInteger int1 = new BigInteger("131224324234234234234313");
    //BigInteger int2 = new BigInteger("13345663456346435648234313");

    BigInteger int1, int2, result; 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter first bigInteger: ");
    int1 = sc.nextBigInteger();

    System.out.println("Enter second bigInteger: ");
    int2 = sc.nextBigInteger();

    result = int1.multiply(int2);

    System.out.println("Result: " +result);

 }
}
```